# Passing multiple metadara tags with kwargs from variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I'm trying to pass metadata tags that I generated with code.

```
import ffmpeg 
    
tags = {'metadata:g:0':"artist=various artists", 'metadata:g:1':"title=title" , 'metadata:g:2':"network=network", 'metadata:g:3':"show=show",'metadata:g:4':"description=description" ,'metadata:g:5':"genre=genre", 'metadata:g:6':"MediaCreateDate=2015:07:09 00:00:00Z"}

process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mp4')
    .output('output.mp4', codec='copy', map_metadata='0', **{tags})
    .run()
)
```

I get this error:

.output('output.mp4', codec='copy', map_metadata='0', **{tags})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I try to pass it not as variable, it works:

```
process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mp4')
    .output('output.mp4', codec='copy', map_metadata='0', **{'metadata:g:0':"artist=various artists", 'metadata:g:1':"title=title" , 'metadata:g:2':"network=network", 'metadata:g:3':"show=show",'metadata:g:4':"description=description" ,'metadata:g:5':"genre=genre", 'metadata:g:6':"MediaCreateDate=2015:07:09 00:00:00Z"})
    .run()
)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

and with:

```
import ffmpeg 
    
tags = {'metadata:g:0':"artist=various artists", 'metadata:g:1':"title=title" , 'metadata:g:2':"network=network", 'metadata:g:3':"show=show",'metadata:g:4':"description=description" ,'metadata:g:5':"genre=genre", 'metadata:g:6':"MediaCreateDate=2015:07:09 00:00:00Z"}

process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mp4')
    .output('output.mp4', codec='copy', map_metadata='0', **tags)
    .run()
)
```

It's OK ?

```
x = { "a":1, "b": 2 }

def SuperTest(**kwargs):
  print(kwargs)

SuperTest(**x) # OK
SuperTest(**{x}) # Error
```